# creating ./config.data failed while compiling Mozilla Firefox

Tags: python, c++, firefox, mozilla

My mozilla compilation is failing while I am compiling with command. I am just using the default code from mozilla.

```
mach build
```

with followig error

```
2:39.43 creating ./config.data
 2:46.33
 2:53.91
 2:54.26 Creating config.status
 2:54.26 Traceback (most recent call last):
 2:54.26   File "c:/mozilla-source/mozilla-central/configure.py", line 124, in <module>
 2:54.26     sys.exit(main(sys.argv))
 2:54.26   File "c:/mozilla-source/mozilla-central/configure.py", line 34, in main
 2:54.26     return config_status(config)
 2:54.26   File "c:/mozilla-source/mozilla-central/configure.py", line 109, in config_status
 2:54.26     from mozbuild.config_status import config_status
 2:54.26   File "c:\mozilla-source\mozilla-central\python\mozbuild\mozbuild\config_status.py", line 21, in <module>
 2:54.26     from mozbuild.base import MachCommandConditions
 2:54.26   File "c:\mozilla-source\mozilla-central\python\mozbuild\mozbuild\base.py", line 17, in <module>
 2:54.26     from mach.mixin.process import ProcessExecutionMixin
 2:54.26   File "c:\mozilla-source\mozilla-central\python\mach\mach\mixin\process.py", line 14, in <module>
 2:54.26     from mozprocess.processhandler import ProcessHandlerMixin
 2:54.26 ImportError: No module named mozprocess.processhandler
 2:54.37 *** Fix above errors and then restart with\
 2:54.37                "c:/mozilla-build/mozmake/mozmake.EXE -f client.mk build"
 2:54.39 c:/mozilla-source/mozilla-central/client.mk:379: recipe for target 'configure' failed
 2:54.39 mozmake.EXE[2]: *** [configure] Error 1
 2:54.39 c:/mozilla-source/mozilla-central/client.mk:396: recipe for target 'c:/mozilla-source/mozilla-central/obj-i686-pc-mingw32/Makefile' failed
 2:54.39 mozmake.EXE[1]: *** [c:/mozilla-source/mozilla-central/obj-i686-pc-mingw32/Makefile] Error 2
 2:54.39 client.mk:170: recipe for target 'build' failed
 2:54.39 mozmake.EXE: *** [build] Error 2
 2:54.41 0 compiler warnings present.
2
```

The following line is giving the error

```
if config.get('MOZ_BUILD_APP') != 'js' or config.get('JS_STANDALONE'):
    os.environ[b'WRITE_MOZINFO'] = b'1'
    from mozbuild.config_status import config_status
```

How to fix this one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ran into the same problem, and the existing solutions here didn't help me.

I had run ./bootstrap.py before, to install the system-level dependencies.

There is also a `./mach bootstrap` step that creates a `_virtualenv` dir in objdir and installs the python modules there. Apparently it didn't consider my objdir configuration, so it installed in the wrong dir. Then the build somehow only half-created it.

I fixed it by deleting all `_virtualdev`, and starting `./mach build` again. That then automatically set up _virtualdev correctly this time, and started the build correctly.

No need for `./mach bootstrap`, it will be done automatically. Don't use `make -f client.mk`. It doesn't do all the bootstrapping. Just `./bootstrap.py` and `./mach build` should suffice.

Answer (score 0):

In **mozilla-source\mozilla-central\python\** **mozprocess** libraries were missing.
You need to download the **mozprocess** libraries from https://pypi.python.org/pypi/mozprocess/0.8 and extract to **mozilla-source\mozilla-central\python\** and compile again. It should compile fine.

Comment: That's really unlikely that you need to manually do that. You're probably missing some preprocessing step, as calling "./mach bootstrap".

Comment: I had done all the steps but stil that folder was missing from python directory.